# peer dependencies not getting installed even after installing them manually

Tags: reactjs

My github repo which contain the code of website.
https://github.com/Arpita309/w3dev

Blank page is shown even after deployment and deployment log shows error the peer dependencies not installed .Peer dependencies are not getting added even after manually installing them.

Comment: It's not blank for me.

Comment: can you possibly tell what could be the error in my deployment??

Comment: Are you using IE by any chance? If I open that website in IE it is blank indeed. Works properly in chrome and firefox.